# How do I obtain dependency inside RavenDB query result

Tags: castle-windsor, ravendb

I'm trying to modify BackgroundTask from [TekPub BackgroundTask](https://github.com/ayende/TekPub.Profiler.BackOffice/blob/master/TekPub.Profiler.BackOffice/Tasks/BackgroundTask.cs).

In my background task I need a dependency from an external service and I don't know where I can inject this dependency.

I can create an overload of Run() that include the dependency Run(IMyService) but my TaskExecutor must have a switch clause to inject the correct dependency for the current task.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a public property on the BackgroundTask to do this. No problem with this approach.

Comment: and how do you inject the correct instance of the service needed?

Comment: I wire up my services on my own, but if I'd like to - Ninject has good support for populating public properties.

Comment: I don't understand.. so in your "TaskRunner" you have a list of 

if (task is Type1Task){ .. typedTask.Service=Ioc.Resolve<T1Service>(); ..
}

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're trying to do. I didn't know that you wanted a dependency on just one single specific task. In this case, I'd probably use a locator pattern inside the task itself, effectively resolving the dependency inside the constructor or so.